Measure on $2^{\aleph_0}$ and CH
In Jech's"Set Theory" book, one can read Corollary 10.17 :
If there is a measure on $2^{\aleph_0}$, then $2^{\aleph_0}>\aleph_1$.
Proof :
If $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_1$, then there exists an $ω_1$-scale; a scale $\langle f_{\alpha} : α<ω_1 \rangle$ is
constructed by transfinite induction to $ω_1$ :
Let ${g_{\alpha} : \alpha<ω_1}$ enumerate all functions from ω to ω. At stage $\alpha$, we
construct, by diagonalization, a function $f_{\alpha}$ such that for all β<α, $f_{\alpha} > f_{\beta}$
and $f_{\alpha} > g_{\beta}$. Then $\langle f_{\alpha} : \alpha<ω_1\rangle$ is an ω_1-scale.
I do not understand how he constructs the sequence $\langle f_{\alpha} : \alpha<\omega_1\rangle$, can someone show me explicitly how this sequence is contructed ?

See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4259576/question-about-the-proof-of-ulams-theorem

We repeatedly ($\omega_1$-many times, to be precise) apply the following lemma:

For any countable set $X$ of functions $\omega\rightarrow\omega$, there is a function $h:\omega\rightarrow\omega$ dominating each $f\in X$.

To prove this, let $\{h_i:i\in\omega\}$ enumerate $X$ possibly with repetition (e.g. if $X$ is finite), and define $$f: n\mapsto 1+\sum_{i\le n}h_i(n).$$
Now the iteration of this lemma is a bit clever. We initially might take $f_\eta$ to be gotten by applying the lemma to the set $\{g_\alpha:\alpha<\eta\}.$ But this won't satisfy the requirement that $f_\eta$ dominates each "earlier" $f_\alpha$. To fix this, we dynamically add the $f$s themselves to the sets of functions we're lemma-ing: we double-recursively define $$X_\eta=\{g_\alpha:\alpha\le\eta\}\cup\{f_\alpha:\alpha<\eta\}$$ (in particular, the "initial case" $X_0=\{g_0\}$ doesn't require any $f$s to be built yet) and let $f_\eta$ be built from $X_\eta$ via the lemma above.
(Note that there's a small amount of the axiom of choice required here: we need, essentially, a family $\{b_\alpha:\alpha<\omega_1\}$ with $b_\alpha:\alpha\rightarrow\omega$ injective. Over ZF alone the existence of such a set is unprovable; in fact, it's consistent with $\mathsf{ZF}$ that $\omega_1$ is a countable union of countable sets!)
